# Is overlapping but not connected geometry bad?

Tags: geometry

In hard surface modeling, I sometimes end up with overlapping faces whose vertices aren't connected:

[image: extruding results in overlapping geometry]

Is this bad geometry, and should I try to connect them with vertices, or is this totally fine?
The models are for use in games / for practicing and just for fun.

Comment: I don't know why the image looks corrupted in the post. It's fine on imgur.

Comment: If you encounter a situation where you have 2 faces that share the same geometrical space, sometimes the camera has a hard time deciding which face should be shown in "front". This is known as z-fighting, and usually manifests as a flickering on the surface of the model where the two faces share a space.  This can be visually distracting/realism breaking, so it's best to be avoided if possible. Also - historically, making model assets for games came with the task of producing as few faces as possible in the final model - 2 faces in one spot would have been a massive no-no a few years back.

Comment: Most of the time it doesn't result in z-fighting, as it's inside the mesh. Also, sometimes avoiding this kind of geometry results in more faces. In the example I would have to add an edge loop, which could potentially add many more faces.

Comment: If you know that most of the time it doesn't result in z-fighting and keeps face numbers down, you already have your answer. By the way, if you simply delete the bottom face of the extrude, there is no z-fighting and you even have one face less than before. No need for edge loop and connecting (this would be necessary for beveling maybe). By the way, the preview looks messy because the background is a fine pattern and the preview is scaled down which leads to interference patterns, Moiré effects etc.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered objectively. For instance, try to add a bevel modifier to this geometry : You won't be able to. Try to 3D print ? You will have to remesh it. Try to use a boolean modifier ? You will most certainly run into artifacts. But it will render just fine in Unity, provided you make sure you don't have Z fighting. It really depends on your end goal. The best bet if you want clean geometry is to always keep manifold meshes with quad topology. In your case I would create a whole new object in place of your extrusion. Helps keeping the polygon number low too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays you can do this with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> -> *Extrude Manifold*.

[image]

but it does generate two pentagons that have to be knifed away.

Answer (score 0):

Should you avoid it? Yes.

Does it necessarily look bad?

It depends on the direction of the normals of the two overlapping faces.
If the normals are facing the same way you might have some bizarre results in Unity or other game engines. If they're facing different ways and you're using a 1 sided material shader it's not going to look wrong, just 2 sided, and you might not even notice it because a side would be on the inside, and if one only cares about triangle/face count it's totally ignorable.

Anyway, yes, as I said, do avoid overlapping things if you can.